# Xcode - Pass data between view controllers, then cast to integer

Tags: ios, swift

I have a textfield in my first View Controller. The input is numbers only, but it's obviously in the form of a string. I've passed it to my second view controller. The code is as follows:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class View3on3Results : UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var APResult1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var APResult2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var APResult3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var APResult4: UILabel!

var AP1: String? = String()
var AP2: String? = String()
var AP3: String? = String()

let x:Int? = Int(AP1)


override func viewDidLoad() {

    APResult1.text = AP1
    APResult2.text = AP2

}
}
```

I set the Label text to equal the strings I passed just to test if it was working; it is.

I'd now like to cast the strings I just passed to integers. I tried doing that with:

```
let x:Int? = Int(AP1)
```

It throws the error: View3on3Results.type does not have a member named 'AP1'. Anyone know what's up with this?

All coded in XCode 7.0 beta 3, using Swift 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not Initialise your instance that way but you can do that in `viewDidLoad` method this way:

```
let x:Int? = AP1?.toInt()
```